# Trouble searching and refining mapped managed property

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-property, content-search-web-part, crawled-property

I have a search web part Employee Directory that I'm working on.

To refine & search by office location, I put the values in on-prem AD under "Office" or "physicalDeliveryOfficeName" in attribute editor. This was synced to SPO's UPS, it's mapped to "People:Office" crawled property. This crawled property is mapped to "OfficeNumber" managed property.

Since "OfficeNumber" property is not refinable nor searchable, I went into "RefinableString00" and mapped "People:Office" crawled property to it.

I am still not able to search by "RefinableString00: usa", while "OfficeNumber: usa" works perfectly to narrow down a search.

Waiting for next crawl is not the problem, it's been a long time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried running a full crawl? Moreover, have you included `RefinableString00` in the search display template?

Comment: I have in fact did a full crawl weeks ago. I'm kinda picking this project back up, and just ran a full crawl again before I left work. It technically says full-indexing but also there's no button that says "run a crawl". And RefinableString00 is not defined in the display template, no, but I would think that it still should show values in the refiner web part edit window where you set the refiners. Other ones work fine and show values without necessarily being in the display template like Department, but RefinableString00 never has any values. I'll still give that a try tho.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Site settings->Search->Search and offline availability, click “Reindex site”.

Then wait the SharePoint crawl if you use SharePoint Online or start a full crawl if you use SharePoint On-premise.

Comment: I already did this multiple times to no avail. RefinableString00 still has no values as a refiner